# fabricjs IText - Clear Character Specific Styles

Tags: fabricjs

I need to be able to set the fontFamily for an entire IText object even if it has character specific styling (code example and jsfiddle below). Note, when changing the fontFamily the character-specific styles don't change. Is there a way for me to access and clear those styles and then apply the style to the entire set of characters?

http://jsfiddle.net/xmfw65qg/48/

```
var iTextSample = new fabric.IText('hello\nworld', {
styles: {
    0: {
      0: { textDecoration: 'underline', fontSize: 80 },
      1: { textBackgroundColor: 'red' }
    },
    1: {
      0: { textBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,255,0,0.5)' },
      4: { fontSize: 20 }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

#### 2020 May Edit

In later revisions of fabricJS, the method `removeStyle(props)` has been added.
That means you can do:

```
myTextObject.removeStyle('fontFamily');
```

to clean it up.

You also have:

```
myTextObject.cleanStyle('fontFamily');
```

That will instead remove all the fontaFamily properties that are duplicated of the main object. So that the style object is reduced in complexity if possible.

#### Original answer

http://jsfiddle.net/asturur/xmfw65qg/50/

you have to manually iterate the style object and clear the fontFamily property.

```
function setFont(name, value) {
  var object = canvas.item(0);
  if (!object) return;
  if (object.styles) {
    var styles = object.styles;
    for (var row in styles) {
      for (var char in styles[row]) {
        if ('fontFamily' in styles[row][char]) {
          delete styles[row][char]['fontFamily'];
        }
      }
    }
  }

    object.set(name, value).setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
}
```

why this is necessary is another matter.
I would open an issue on the github repository for that.

Edit:
As fabricjs released 1.6.2 a small bug that was causing the original style object to be changed during rendering, has been fixed.

Comment: It's been a long time since this was answered.  Is this answer still relevant or is there now a better way to do this with the API (I'm on version 3.x of fabricjs)?

Comment: Works beautifully, btw.